# remote access from Windows

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I am new to Ubuntu and I have could not solve one of my issues regarding remote access to my workstation.

I am using Ubuntu for work, previously I had a win 7 based workstation and many times I connected to the workstation from my laptop from home or when I was traveling.

Reading different forums I managed to set up a remote desktop from my laptop to my new Ubuntu workstation and it is working just fine, however I still have a big issue. Previously from win to win remote desktop I always saw exactly the same screen as if I would sit in front of my workstation. Now when I access my Ubuntu workstation from my laptop I have a new desktop and cannot see the running processes, or at least do not know how to see them. For example I start a simulation on my Ubuntu workstation with graphical interface and would like to check from home what is the status of my simulation, I cannot see it with my current remote desktop access. Can you please help me out what to do? Is it possible such a remote access to Ubuntu?

A second problem what I face is with win to win remote desktop I could copy file as well. Is it possible to copy files from Ubuntu to my laptop remotely? If yes how?

Thanks
Sandor

Answer (score 0):

you are running the remote desktop service as system user providing a  login service in ubuntu so you get an individual desktop session , if you run the remote desktop service as a user once logged into the ubuntu desktop you can share that desktop.

to share your current desktop:

open the menu with the windows key
type 'desktop sharing' to find the desktop sharing config
use the dialog to enable and configure desktop sharing.

be sure to use a strong password and turn it off when you aren't using it.